# How to remove the border in twitter widget

Tags: css, twitter, widget, smarty, customization

I am trying to in include twitter widget in my web site. It is developed using `Smarty` . I am trying to customize the widget. Now it has a scroll bar in the right section. I think we can remove that by adding a style `overflow:hidden` to the class `stream`. But I am not sure how can we do that . I have tried with an external css file , but it is not working. Please help me to customize it by removing the scroll bar.

```
 <a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/username"  data-widget-id="myid" width="376" height="200">Tweets by @name</a>

{literal}
<script>
     !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if(!d.getElementById(id)){
          js=d.createElement(s);
          js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
     }}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
{/literal}
```

Please check the page here http://www.jobslamp.com/test.php

New code
    -------------

```
   <div class="clear"></div>{literal}
<style TYPE="text/css">
#footer {
   background-image: none !important;
  }
    </style>{/literal}
    <a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/username"  data-widget-  id="myid"    width="376" height="200" style="border:1px solid red !important;">Tweets by   @username</a>

 {literal}<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)   [0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");   </script>{/literal}
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Try using `!important`.

Comment: Thanks for your time , could u plz inform me how can I use it . Sorry I did not use it before

Comment: `.stream { overflow: hidden !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

try this css:

```
#footer {
background-image: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and suggestion. I have updated the code , but no improvement . Please take a look at http://www.jobslamp.com/test.php

Answer (score -1):

No need to disable all. Just use new parameter provided by the API :

```
<a href="your_timeline" data-chrome="noscrollbar" ...
```

[source = dev.twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines#customization)